# The Green Led of ethernet port of my RPI4 doesn't light up when wired to router but light up with laptop

Tags: pi-4

I formated my SD card using SD card formatter and I downloaded (2020-08-20-raspios-buster-armhf-full.img) and write it on the SD card using (win32diskimager-1.0.0-install.exe). So i have get my Boot folder. I have created the SSH file withot extension and installed Mobaxterm. When I put the ethernet port of the RPI4 in the router the green led doesn't light up only the orange one. But I wire it to my laptop the two leds light up. When I open mobaxterm the network scanner can't also connect to the RPI4 using the SSH protocol. Can anyone Help me?

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: @jsotola, I follow all the steps to configure my RPI4 without Screen or Keyboard. But when i wire the ethernet port to the router the green led not lighting and i can't connect to the RPI using the SSH and when i use Putty the erreur is "Host does not exist". Thank you.

Comment: it is like you saying `my kitchen light does not come on` when you know that the power to your house is turned off ... there is nothing wrong with the green light .... you have a problem with network connection

Answer (score 3):

Because the connection  works with your laptop (green ethernet LED is on) then the problem must be the router. Check its setting on the port to the RasPi. The Raspberry Pi 4B supports up to 1 GBit. Maybe that's a problem for your router? Try another port. Check if the port is set to auto-negotiation. Try to set its speed to fix 100 MBit. The RasPi should realize it authomaticaly. Try another ethernet cable.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the possible corruption of the image due to using win32diskimager rather than the recommended tool the problem is probably Ethernet cabling.

The Pi4 has a Gigabit interface which requires a properly wired Gigabit 4 pair cable.

You have provided insufficient information to give a definitive answer.

Comment: ,Cloud the win32diskimager cause a problem?. The ethernet cable is 4 pairs and it comes with the RPI4.Could it be the version of the Raspbien? Thank you.

Comment: @sarramarmouche If you choose to ignore the [Foundation recommendations](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/) it is your responsibility to ensure it is correct. If connected to a Gigabit interface LED0 (green on Pi4) indicates Speed/Activity by default. It is difficult to do any diagnostics without a screen or keyboard.